# ml64.exe is failing on Windows8 x64 machine

Tags: windows-8, build, compilation, 64-bit

There is the build rule (below) which was used to compile x64 assembly with Visual Studio 2005. It works well but the issue is appearing on Windows8 machine. And compiler fires the next error:

```
1>Assembling x64...
1>Project : error PRJ0003 : Error spawning 'cmd.exe'.
```

while 32bin assembly builds successfully. Any ideas how to fix it?

The rule is located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\VCProjectDefaults" directory and ml64.exe in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\amd64" and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\x86_amd64".

> < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   < VisualStudioToolFile
>       Name="Microsoft Macro Assembler x64"
>       Version="8.00">
>
> ```
>         <Properties>
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="NoLogo"
>                 DisplayName="Suppress Startup Banner"
>                 Description="Suppress the display of the startup banner and information messages.     (/nologo)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/nologo"
>                 DefaultValue="true"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="TinyMemoryModelSupport"
>                 DisplayName="Tiny Memory Model Support"
>                 PropertyPageName="Advanced"
>                 Description="Enables tiny-memory-model support. Note that this is not equivalent to the .MODEL TINY directive.     (/AT)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/AT"
>             />
>             <StringProperty
>                 Name="ObjectFileName"
>                 DisplayName="Object File Name"
>                 PropertyPageName="Object File"
>                 Description="Specifies the name of the output object file.     (/Fo:[file])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Fo&quot;[value]&quot;"
>                 DefaultValue="$(IntDir)\$(InputName).obj"
>             />
>             <EnumProperty
>                 Name="PreserveIdentifierCase"
>                 DisplayName="Preserve Identifier Case"
>                 Description="Specifies preservation of case of user identifiers.     (/Cp, /Cu, /Cx)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 DefaultValue="0"
>
>                 <Values>
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="0"
>                         DisplayName="Default"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="1"
>                         Switch="/Cp"
>                         DisplayName="Preserves Identifier Case (/Cp)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="2"
>                         Switch="/Cu"
>                         DisplayName="Maps all identifiers to upper case. (/Cu)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="3"
>                         Switch="/Cx"
>                         DisplayName="Preserves case in public and extern symbols. (/Cx)"
>                     />
>                 </Values>
>             </EnumProperty>
>             <StringProperty
>                 Name="PreprocessorDefinitions"
>                 DisplayName="Preprocessor Definitions"
>                 Description="Defines a text macro with the given name.     (/D[symbol])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/D&quot;[value]&quot;"
>                 Delimited="true"
>                 Inheritable="true"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="GeneratePreprocessedSourceListing"
>                 DisplayName="Generate Preprocessed Source Listing"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Generates a preprocessed source listing to the Output Window.     (/EP)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/EP"
>             />
>             <StringProperty
>                 Name="AssembledCodeListingFile"
>                 DisplayName="Assembled Code Listing File"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Generates an assembled code listing file.     (/Fl[file])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Fl&quot;[value]&quot;"
>             />
>             <StringProperty
>                 Name="SourceListingLineWidth"
>                 DisplayName="Source Listing Line Width"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Sets the line width of source listing in characters per line. Range is 60 to 255. Same as PAGE width.     (/Sl [width])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Sl [value]"
>             />
>             <StringProperty
>                 Name="SourceListingPageLength"
>                 DisplayName="Source Listing Page Length"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Sets the page length of source listing in lines per page. Range is 10 to 255. Same as PAGE length.     (/Sp [length])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Sp [value]"
>             />
>             <StringProperty
>                 Name="IncludePaths"
>                 DisplayName="Include Paths"
>                 Description="Sets path for include file. A maximum of 10 /I options is allowed.     (/I [path])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/I &quot;[value]&quot;"
>                 Delimited="true"
>                 Inheritable="true"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="ListAllAvailableInformation"
>                 DisplayName="List All Available Information"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Turns on listing of all available information.     (/Sa)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Sa"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="UseSafeExceptionHandlers"
>                 DisplayName="Use Safe Exception Handlers"
>                 PropertyPageName="Advanced"
>                 Description="Marks the object as either containing no exception handlers or containing exception handlers that are all declared with .SAFESEH.     (/safeseh)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/safeseh"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="AddFirstPassListing"
>                 DisplayName="Add First Pass Listing"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Adds first-pass listing to listing file.     (/Sf)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Sf"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="EnableAssemblyGeneratedCodeListing"
>                 DisplayName="Enable Assembly Generated Code Listing"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Turns on listing of assembly-generated code.     (/Sg)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Sg"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="DisableSymbolTable"
>                 DisplayName="Disable Symbol Table"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Turns off symbol table when producing a listing.     (/Sn)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Sn"
>             />
>             <StringProperty
>                 Name="SourceListingSubTitle"
>                 DisplayName="Source Listing Subtitle"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Specifies subtitle text for source listing. Same as SUBTITLE text.     (/Ss [subtitle])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Ss [value]"
>             />
>             <StringProperty
>                 Name="SourceListingTitle"
>                 DisplayName="Source Listing Title"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Specifies title for source listing. Same as TITLE text.     (/St [title])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/St [value]"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="EnableFalseConditionalsInListing"
>                 DisplayName="Enable False Conditionals In Listing"
>                 PropertyPageName="Listing File"
>                 Description="Turns on false conditionals in listing.     (/Sx)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Sx"
>             />
>             <EnumProperty
>                 Name="WarningLevel"
>                 DisplayName="Warning Level"
>                 Description="Sets the warning level, where level = 0, 1, 2, or 3.    (/W0, /W1, /W2, /W3)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 DefaultValue="3"
>
>                 <Values>
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="0"
>                         Switch="/W0"
>                         DisplayName="Warning Level 0 (/W0)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="1"
>                         Switch="/W1"
>                         DisplayName="Warning Level 1 (/W1)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="2"
>                         Switch="/W2"
>                         DisplayName="Warning Level 2 (/W2)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="3"
>                         Switch="/W3"
>                         DisplayName="Warning Level 3 (/W3)"
>                     />
>                 </Values>
>             </EnumProperty>
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="TreatWarningsAsErrors"
>                 DisplayName="Treat Warnings As Errors"
>                 Description="Returns an error code if warnings are generated.     (/WX)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/WX"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="MakeAllSymbolsPublic"
>                 DisplayName="Make All Symbols Public"
>                 PropertyPageName="Object File"
>                 Description="Makes all symbols public.     (/Zf)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Zf"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="GenerateDebugInformation"
>                 DisplayName="Generate Debug Information"
>                 Description="Generates Debug Information.     (/Zi)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Zi"
>                 DefaultValue="true"
>             />
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="EnableMASM51Compatibility"
>                 DisplayName="Enable MASM 5.1 Compatibility"
>                 Description="Enables M510 option for maximum compatibility with MASM 5.1.     (/Zm)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Zm"
>             />
>             <EnumProperty
>                 Name="PackAlignmentBoundary"
>                 DisplayName="Pack Alignment Boundary"
>                 PropertyPageName="Advanced"
>                 Description="Packs structures on the specified byte boundary. The alignment can be 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16.     (/Zp1, /Zp2, /Zp4, /Zp8, /Zp16)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>
>                 <Values>
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="0"
>                         DisplayName="Default"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="1"
>                         Switch="/Zp1"
>                         DisplayName="One Byte Boundary (/Zp1)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="2"
>                         Switch="/Zp2"
>                         DisplayName="Two Byte Boundary (/Zp2)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="3"
>                         Switch="/Zp4"
>                         DisplayName="Four Byte Boundary (/Zp4)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="4"
>                         Switch="/Zp8"
>                         DisplayName="Eight Byte Boundary (/Zp8)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="5"
>                         Switch="/Zp16"
>                         DisplayName="Sixteen Byte Boundary (/Zp16)"
>                     />
>                 </Values>
>             </EnumProperty>
>             <BooleanProperty
>                 Name="PerformSyntaxCheckOnly"
>                 DisplayName="Perform Syntax Check Only"
>                 Description="Performs a syntax check only.     (/Zs)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/Zs"
>             />
>             <EnumProperty
>                 Name="CallingConvention"
>                 DisplayName="Calling Convention"
>                 PropertyPageName="Advanced"
>                 Description="Selects calling convention for your application.     (/Gc, /Gd. /Gz)"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>
>                 <Values>
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="0"
>                         DisplayName="Default"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="1"
>                         Switch="/Gd"
>                         DisplayName="Use C-style Calling Convention (/Gd)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="2"
>                         Switch="/Gz"
>                         DisplayName="Use stdcall Calling Convention (/Gz)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="3"
>                         Switch="/Gc"
>                         DisplayName="Use Pascal Calling Convention (/Gc)"
>                     />
>                 </Values>
>             </EnumProperty>
>             <EnumProperty
>                 Name="ErrorReporting"
>                 DisplayName="Error Reporting"
>                 PropertyPageName="Advanced"
>                 Description="Reports internal assembler errors to Microsoft.     (/errorReport:[method])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>
>                 <Values>
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="0"
>                         Switch="/errorReport:prompt"
>                         DisplayName="Prompt to send report immediately (/errorReport:prompt)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="1"
>                         Switch="/errorReport:queue"
>                         DisplayName="Prompt to send report at the next logon (/errorReport:queue)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="2"
>                         Switch="/errorReport:send"
>                         DisplayName="Automatically send report (/errorReport:send)"
>                     />
>                     <EnumValue
>                         Value="3"
>                         Switch="/errorReport:none"
>                         DisplayName="Do not send report (/errorReport:none)"
>                     />
>                 </Values>
>             </EnumProperty>
>             <StringProperty
>                 Name="BrowseFile"
>                 DisplayName="Generate Browse Information File"
>                 PropertyPageName="Advanced"
>                 Description="Specifies whether to generate browse information file and its optional name or location of the browse information file.     (/FR[name])"
>                 HelpURL="http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vcmasm/html/vclrfml.asp"
>                 Switch="/FR&quot;[value]&quot;"
>                 Delimited="true"
>                 Inheritable="true"
>             />
>         </Properties>
>     </CustomBuildRule>
> </Rules>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error spawning 'cmd.exe'.

Your machine is pretty messed up, Visual Studio cannot start the command processor.  First you need to check if `cmd.exe` is still located in the c:\windows\system32 directory.  Next you need to check if your environment variables are still correct.  Which is the more typical mishap, uninstallers tend to screw this up.

Start + Control Panel, System, Advanced, Environment Variables button.  Look at the System variables displayed there.  The ComSpec variable needs to point to c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.  The Path environment variable needs to start with c:\windows\system32;c:\windows.  I'm using the default names for these directories, small chance that they are different on your machine.  Log out and log back in to make changes effective.

Comment: Hans, thanks you for pointing me to the right direction. "C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows" were missing in the Path environment variable.